# I Getting file names for the file upload element but i want replace that list when attached again

Tags: javascript, file-upload

Here i have code for taking info about attached files:

```
<ul id="result"></ul>


<script>
        

var elem = document.getElementById('upload-field');
elem.addEventListener('change', getFileData);

function getFileData() {
  const files = this.files;
  const list = document.getElementById("result");
  let child;
  
  for ( let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    child = document.createElement("li")
    child.textContent = files[i].name;
    
    list.append(child);
  }
}



</script>
```

but when I click on the button and attach the file - it shows this file info.

When I do it again code added this file info again under the previous text, and I would like to "reset" the list of files when I attach files again, but I don't know how to improve this code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the `<input type="file" id="upload-field">` to your example. If you wanted to reset the file control you would use a form around it. But since you wanted to "reset" the element, setting it's innerHTML to empty would suffice.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('upload-field');
elem.addEventListener('change', getFileData);

function getFileData() {
  const files = this.files;
  const list = document.getElementById("result");
  
  // empty list
  list.innerHTML = "";
  
  let child;

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    child = document.createElement("li")
    child.textContent = files[i].name;

    list.append(child);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="upload-field">
<ul id="result"></ul>
```